# Neither user 10031 nor current process has android.permission.INSTALL_PACKAGES

Tags: java, android, android-package-managers

I want to use PackageManager to install self apk, but I have some problems.

PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();

pm.installPackage(Uri.fromFile(file), null,
PackageManager.INSTALL_REPLACE_EXISTING, pakcageName);

java.lang.SecurityException: Neither user 10031 nor current process has android.permission.INSTALL_PACKAGES.
at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1322)
at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1276)
at android.content.pm.IPackageManager$Stub$Proxy.installPackage(IPackageManager.java:1951)
at android.app.ContextImpl$ApplicationPackageManager.installPackage(ContextImpl.java:2549)

Answer (score -1):

As the error says, your app does not have permission to install packages.

put:

```
<uses-permission name="android.permission.INSTALL_PACKAGES"/>
```

In your manifest that should get you started.

Comment: Is this method need to root the device?

Comment: No rooting should not be required. With that permission set, try rebooting the device, and if that still doesn't work, uninstall and reinstall the apk, you will get a new uid assigned to your app.

Comment: INSTALL_PACKAGES is a system level permission. You will need either root or the system certificate to get it to work.